# Electromotive force in terms of thermodynamics / statistical physics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, electric-circuits, electricity

I would like to understand how electromotive force arises in terms of thermodynamics/ statistical physics. It seems like a rather simple question, but my (admittedly brief) search hasn't produced anything useful. Full answers, references to other answers/books or simply relevant keywords are appreciated.

**Clarification:** I mean specifically electrochemical emf, produced by batteries, accumulators, etc. Thanks to @GiorgioP for pointing the need for this clarification.

Comment: There are ways to produce emf that have nothing to do with thermodynamics or statistical mechanics. I think you should narrow your request.

Comment: @GiorgioP thanks. I added a clarification.